# ASP.NET Application log while code is running / progress bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, progress-bar, message-queue

I’m building a OCR scanning module in my ASP forms webapplication. As you may know a operation like that can take some time. Therefor I’m using a background service application that responds to a message queue that runs the code so the user does not even have to stay on the same webpage.

What I would like to do is inform the user what is going on while the service is running. If lets say the user uploaded 5 documents I would like to see something like this appear in a literal, label or repeater control. These items do not have to be saved in a database and I don’t want then to.

*Processing document 1 of 5

Document 1 processed with code 6732842

Processing document 2 of 5

Document 2 processed with code 8732457

Processing document 3 of 5

Document 3 processed with code 8725347

Processing document 4 of 5 

Document 4 could not be processed “no OCR string recognized”

Processing document 5 of 5

Document 5 processed with code 4372537

Completed: Processed 4 of 5 documents received*

If an error occurred I would like to see something like this

*An error occurred. The scanning process has been stopped.*

I have some idears but I don’t know what’s the best practice.

Option 1:
I could save above items in a static class and let javascript post every 5 sec. to get 
that value via a web method.

Option 2:
I could save above items in the session returning a updated session object when I let       JavaScript post every 5 sec. I don’t know if this is available when using a service         Application.

If you have any other options (preferably better ones) that would be greatly appriciated.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the progress items in a database , give each user's upload with a different id, publish this data with a web service.  In the browser, use JavaScipt to retrieve the progress from the web service.
Of course, the database need to delete periodically, e.g., every minitue.

Comment: It’s not the prettiest option but it seems to be the lesser of two worsts. I simply update a record in every loop and a async postbacktrigger on the to get the data and refresh the control on the page.
@jcalabris, Thank you for the info. And yes I will get into depth with MVC making my life just a little easier “I hope”.

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could give you a working example, but what you're wanting to do is not easy, and is made even more difficult by the fact that you're not using ASP.NET MVC which makes async work easier. You're going to need to write a series of asynchronous tasks to do some work for you. This article will give you a good start: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2010/04/14/performing-asynchronous-work-or-tasks-in-asp-net-applications.aspx