# Updating the UI right before running the BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have this really little problem, but which can't be easily solved. Currently, my program has 2 buttons, a "Start" and a "Cancel". When the user clicks the start, the buttons should go instantly:

> StartButton.IsEnabled = false;
>
> CancelButton.IsEnabled = true;

But this occurs only when the BackgroundWorker has finished (all the code which will be ran after pressing the button), because the UI is always updated as last. There's no way I could add these commands to the "ProgressChanged" or "Completed" event of the backgroundworker. These events can take up to 10min to complete.

One easy way is to add these commands to the "ProgressChanged" part, and in the end "Complete" change their state again. But I'd like to avoid this, as the buttons should be showing their real state all the time, not after few "ProgressChanged" events. Of course there's always ways around, like not using the button's UI properties.

Is there any short solution for this?

It doesn't work to add the Button.Property changes to the ClickEvent. That's the main problem in this. I can easily use the "Completed" part of BGW to change the Button's back to match the starting state. The problem is to get them set right before all the events and BGW.

Comment: It seems that the easiest way is to add the property changes to the start of "ProgressChanged" event. However, this isn't always the best way, because sometimes it can take a lot of time before that method is triggered, depending on how often the code gives progress information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a start button like:

```
this.StartButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
```

then you can do

```
this.StartButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

and then do

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     StartButton.IsEnabled = false;

     CancelButton.IsEnabled = true;
     Thread bg = new Thread(new ThreadStart( UpdateDatabase()));
     bg.Start();
  }
```

if you want the `bg` thread to send messages to the UI use the `Invoke` method like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

```
  public delegate void UpdateUIHndler();
  public void UpdateUI()
  {

  }
```

and do

```
     if (InvokeRequired)
     {
        Invoke(new UpdateUIHndler(UpdateUI));
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't change the problem. The situation is exactly the same, exept the "button1_Click" is missing the method to start the BackgroundWorker. Then the BackgroundWorker's commands and calculations will be processed first, and after then the UI updates with these commands:
StartButton.IsEnabled = false;
CancelButton.IsEnabled = true;

Comment: @AshtonWoods then what is the problem? is the UI get stuck?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I'd need to wait for minutes for the BackgroundWorker to complete. After then the UI updates the set configurations, like properties .IsEnabled, .Content.

Comment: @AshtonWoods i'm sorry, but i don't get the problem. why will you have to wait minutes? the event goes off when you click the button, and the UI updates in milliseconds, and if the work is done in a background worker, I.E. different thread, then there should be no problem

Comment: The current program doesn't work that way. The structure is this:
ClickEvent -> StartButton.IsEnabled false; -> UpdateDatabase() which incldues the call to my BackgroundWorker.
My only known way I could access the UI-elements while processing this ClickEvent, is via the BackgroundWorker's "ProgressChanged" and "Complete" methods.

Comment: @AshtonWoods your BackgroundWorker is not a BackgroundWorker, because it is in same thread as the UI, you must pass it to a different thread. i'll show you an example, wait a minute, i'm editing the answer

Comment: I guess this is it. I still have to test it. I can't understand that this much need to be done to update one fancy button. Great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at a previous question of mine (quite similer). I should go for option 1.

[ASP.NET Application log while code is running / progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069829/asp-net-application-log-while-code-is-running-progress-bar)

UI will only be delayed 5 seconds. Instead of text update the button styling using AJAX.

Comment: #Danny
I'm sorry but this is WPF.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable the start button in the click event of that button itself and enable it again it on RunWorkerCompleted event of BGW as shown below

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(_worker_DoWork);

private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   startButton.IsEnabled = false;
}

 void _worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    stratButton.IsEnabled = true;
 }

void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  //Your processing code
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't work. The code is processed through the BGW as it's part of the ClickEvent.

Comment: @AshtonWoods - I don't think it's a good way to keep the processing code in the StartButton_Click event, as BGW is of no use in this scenario. You can put the code in the DoWork event of the BGW as shown in my post

Comment: The ClickEvent calls another Function(), which includes all the further commands, which also calls the BGW. The DoWork includes all the massive commands, which are repeated x times.

Comment: @AshtonWoods That other Function() also you can add in the DoWork  handler. I think it will be difficult to suggest anything without looking your code.